# Connecting Raspberry Pi to network through ethernet

Tags: networking, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

For testing reasons (need a pingable address on this network), I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi on a fiber network with a static IP, connecting with an ethernet cable. The FDX, LNK, and 100 LEDs are all lit (green, green, orange, respectively, if that's relevant).

In /etc/network/interfaces, I have

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address X.X.X.206
 gateway ???
 netmask 255.255.255.252
 network X.X.X.205
 broadcast ???
```

What are the gateway and broadcast addresses, and where should I find them? I am assuming that the network address is the address of my router.

I have taken this configuration from the RPi wiki [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Setting_up_a_static_IP_in_Debian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network address is wrong. It's never an odd number, because it's always the address where the host part (the part where the subnet mask has binary zeroes) is zero.

So your subnet mask (in binary) looks like this:
    11111111.11111111.11111111.11111100

And your network number probably looks like this:
    xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.110011|00
That's X.X.X.204. The host part is zero.

So your router/gateway address is likely:
    xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.110011|01
That's X.X.X.205. The host address part is 1.

And your broadcast address is:
    xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.110011|11
That's X.X.X.207. The host part is all 1's in binary, its max value.

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway will probably be your router's IP if it's in a home environment.  You could look at any PC on the network with ipconfig (windows) ifconfig (mac) and that will show your gateway. Broadcast would be X.X.X.3  Your network would be X.X.X.0